# How to pull data from this json?

Tags: php, json

I've got a json data like this:

```
[["building1.jpg",["uploads\/45\/0\/building1.jpg","uploads\/45\/1\/building1.jpg"],[],"","45",["345:255"]]]
```

And I need to access `uploads\/45\/1\/building1.jpg`, how could I get it with PHP?

For `uploads\/45\/0\/building1.jpg` I'm using `$data[0][1][0]` and it works, but for the `uploads\/45\/1\/building1.jpg` `$data[0][2][0]` doesn't work. What would be the correct approach?

Comment: `$data[0][1][1];` - https://eval.in/408884

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `$data[0][1][1]`, as they're in the same array.

Comment: Yes, this was it :) I'll accept your answer in 12 minutes.